# Unknown Type name char16_t while compiling C code using a header that is used for C++ code

Tags: c++, c, gcc, char16-t

This is my header file,

sample.h

```
#pragma

#ifndef BASETYPES
#define BASETYPES

typedef char16_t WCHAR

#endif
```

This is my C code,

sample.c

```
WCHAR *name;
int main() {
}
```

The above header was initially used by only C++ code. Now I have a C code to compile which uses the same header file.

When I compile the C code using GCC, I am getting the following error,

```
"error G5688306C: unknown type name char16_t"
```

I read this [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56086) and it looks like it isnt really a bug.

Is there any work around or any fix to the problem I am facing? Please suggest.

Comment: How are compiling the code?

Comment: gcc -std=c++ sample.c

Comment: Try `#include <uchar.h>` before using `char16_t`.

Comment: Yeah. But in C++, it is already a predefined built in type. Only for C, I have to include header file right?

Comment: Including <uchar.h> will affect the compilation of C++ code??

Comment: @ShaikSyedAli Well, it requires though to be build with at least with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use c+11 compiler in this case..

Answer (score 2):

`char16_t` is not a built in C type. It was introduced by [C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/char16_t) in the `uchar.h` header. Using C++11 features with GCC is enabled with `-std=c++11`.

If you can't use C++11, you must use another type instead.
[`wchar_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide) or [`uint16_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) may be useful.